# data.table calculation for last row per group

Tags: r, data.table

When I have a grouped data.table

```
library(data.table)
dat <- data.table(id=1:10, group=rep(1:2, each=5), x=rnorm(10))

> dat
    id group           x
 1:  1     1 -0.39384959
 2:  2     1 -0.03081369
 3:  3     1 -1.30571673
 4:  4     1 -1.82379155
 5:  5     1  2.36751011
 6:  6     2  0.21523454
 7:  7     2 -0.18905780
 8:  8     2  1.80707868
 9:  9     2  0.88348164
10: 10     2  0.38374826
```

and I would like to set `x` to zero for the last `id` in each group, I wonder how this can be achieved. My take was `dat[.N, x:=0, by=group]` but this would not work as this changes only the value of id 10. Why is this? The vignette does not seem to help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use:

```
dat[,x:= ifelse(.I == last(.I),0,x),by=.(group)][]



     id group          x
 1:  1     1 -0.6291830
 2:  2     1 -0.1840518
 3:  3     1  0.5242331
 4:  4     1 -1.8604996
 5:  5     1  0.0000000
 6:  6     2 -1.3966630
 7:  7     2  0.8715680
 8:  8     2 -0.6207351
 9:  9     2 -0.3021389
10: 10     2  0.0000000
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is something a bit primitive:

```
dat[, x := ifelse(seq_along(x) == .N, 0, x), group][]
```

More concisely:

```
dat[, x := c(x[-.N], 0), group]
```

Probably more efficient is:

```
dat[dat[, .I[.N], group]$V1, x := 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use `replace`

```
library(data.table)
dat[, x := replace(x, seq_len(.N) == .N, 0),by=group]

dat
#    id group          x
# 1:  1     1 -0.3148360
# 2:  2     1 -0.1737918
# 3:  3     1 -0.6768283
# 4:  4     1  0.4066397
# 5:  5     1  0.0000000
# 6:  6     2 -0.3606155
# 7:  7     2  0.1965135
# 8:  8     2  0.1488247
# 9:  9     2 -1.8684589
#10: 10     2  0.0000000
```

Or simpler approach suggested by @sindri_baldur

```
dat[, x := replace(x, .N, 0),by=group]
```

Comment: Can simplify to `replace(x, .N, 0)`.